# Ubuntu 12.04 - Trouble with UFI Boot on Macbook Pro Retina (late 2013)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, macbook

I used the following tutorial to set up Ubuntu 12.04 as dual boot on the Macbook Pro Retina (late 2013):

I did followed this [article](http://randomtutor.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/installing-ubuntu-1304-on-retina.html)

It sets up Ubuntu as dual boot with EFI Boot only (without Grub). However, I have some issues with the boot configuration... According to the tutorial, the boot manager (ReFind) needs a kernel on the HD of Mac OS X to be able to find it, so I copied the kernel files from Ubuntu to MacOS X in /EFI/ubuntu and provided the information to the boot manager as described in the tutorial.

However, in my case, ReFind can boot the kernel but it fails to boot at the end since it cannot find the folder `/dev/disk/by-uuid` and boots into the initramfs shell. Creating the folder manually and providing a syslink with the UUID as name, linking to the correct partition (in my case `../../sda4`) lets me boot Ubuntu.

Only Problem is that I have to do those settings each time I reboot. As soon as Ubuntu is loaded, the `/etc/disk/by-uuid` folder exists as well as the `/etc/fstab` (which does not exist when booted into initramfs). But when I reboot I can only get to the *initramfs shell* again and have to create the folder and `syslink` again.

So not really sure what is happening there. Does anybody have idea?

It seems like the `/dev/disk/` I get access to from the *initramfs shell* is not the one of the actual Ubuntu. Is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

You need to boot in to OSX and install rEFInd in OSX, Macs dont reconize any version of linux by default, so your need to install it on your OSX partition. After that you reboot your mac and rEFInd should pop up

Comment: He did, his problem is other.